# slideToggle menu and submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with `slideToggle()`. My ul and sub ul close when I click on submenu item. I have ul:

```js
$('.menu-pages li').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu-pages">
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" target="_self" style="">
      <span>Информация</span>
    </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
      <li class="">
        <a href="http://dev.giant.md/page/o-kompanii" target="_self" style="">
          <span>О нас</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="#" target="_self" style="">
          <span>Бренды</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu" style="">
          <li class="">
            <a href="http://dev.giant.md/page/giant" target="_self" style="">
              <span>Giant</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="http://dev.giant.md/page/liv" target="_self" style="">
              <span>Liv</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="http://dev.giant.md/page/shimano" target="_self" style="">
              <span>SHIMANO</span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

When I click on parent li I do `slideToggle()`. But I do `slideToggle` on child `ul > li`. And when I click on child, I close parent ul. How I can do corretcly `slideToggle()` with open/close effect on parent and child separately?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mgrsf90a/

check this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the top-level `<li>` contains the entire sublist, and the `click` event on the menu item is propagating upwards through the DOM, triggering `click` events on its parents, including the top-level `<li>`.

To stop this happening, just use the `stopPropgation` method on the event object:

```
$('.menu-pages li').click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideToggle();   
});
```